# When to use or omit definite/indefinite articles after “après”?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps

Recently I've been dealing more with forming sentences, and, while they're mostly straightforward, I'm having trouble knowing with absolute certainty when to use a definite or indefinite article.

Let's consider the phrase:

> Après le dîner

I understand that this literally translates to 'After the dinner', but it's my understanding that it's able to be used to convey the phrase "After dinner."

This is where I become confused, because I'm not sure if I can validly construct:

> Après dîner

Does it mean the same thing? am I able to say `Après dîner` without grammatical consequence or does it just sound like gibberish? Taking a note from that, does this pattern of `avant/après {NOUN}' apply? or do I always have to stick a definite/indefinite article in front of it?

Merci!

Comment: I'm going to put this as a comment because I don't know for sure. As a native french speaker, both sound fine written as well as orally but I have a feeling that "Après dîner" is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Après le dîner* and *après dîner* are both correct. The *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi) gives usage « Sans prédéterminant » ("Without determiner") as a special case of the sense « **Après** + subst. d'action, subst. à valeur verbale » ("**Après** + action noun, noun with the sense of a verb"). [[link](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/apr%C3%A8s)]

Later in the same entry, it also explicitly clarifies that *dîner* is to be interpreted as the noun ("dinner"), not the infinitive ("to eat dinner"). (Of course, "after eating dinner" would normally be *après avoir dîné*, but the TLFi gives a few citations with *après* plus a plain infinitive — one with *après causer* instead of *après avoir causé*, one with *après boire* instead of *après avoir bu* — hence the clarification.)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, especially with the reference of the TLFi. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Morklympious: You're welcome!